# SUMIF MATCH Conditional in Python

Tags: indexing, conditional-statements, string-matching

I'm trying to use a python version of excel `MATCH`, `INDEX` and `SUMIF`.

Example dataset:

```
A - 1
B - 2
A - 5
C - 6
A - 1
C - 2
```

So if I need to sum `A` it should output `7`.
The issue is that I don't know the variable `A` - I need to use some universal variable that captures all values. So read out `A = 7, B = 2, C = 8`.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you seen `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: Yes, collection doesn't seem to address the issue. I've stories groupby and count().